# Transport.Connect JavaAPI not working

Tags: jakarta-mail

1. I have pasted my code below but i dunno why my code is not working beyond Transport.connect,
   2.just to check the flow i have added step 1, step 2 step 3. In the output i am getting till Step 2. Beyod that there is no response.

   ```
    import javax.mail.*;
    import javax.mail.internet.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class SendFromGmail {
     public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
       String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
       String from = "rageshcv@gmail.com";
       String pass = "mypassword";
       Properties props = System.getProperties();
       props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
       props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
       props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
       props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
       props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
       props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
       System.out.println("step 1");
       String[] to = {"rageshcv@outlook.com"};

       Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
       MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
       InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];


       for( int i=0; i < to.length; i++ ) { 
           toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
       }
       System.out.println(Message.RecipientType.TO);

       for( int i=0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
           message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
       }
       message.setSubject("sending in a group");
       message.setText("Welcome to JavaMail");
       Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
       System.out.println("Step 2");
       transport.connect(host, from, pass);
       System.out.println("Step 3");
       transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
       transport.close();
    }
   catch(Exception e){
       e.getMessage();
      }
      }
      }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug), did you try them?

Quoted text from the linked source:

> Q: How do I debug problems connecting to my mail server?
>
> A: The first thing to do when debugging such problems is to determine whether it's a Java problem or a networking problem. Use telnet to try to connect to the remote system. For example, if you're having trouble connecting to the POP3 server named `mail.example.com`, you would use:
>
> `telnet mail.example.com 110`
>
> If you're trying to connect to an SMTP server, use 25 instead of 110 for the port number. If you're trying to connect to an IMAP server use 143 for the port number.
>
> If you get a greeting banner you can simply disconnect. If this works, your networking, name service, firewall, etc. are all set up correctly and your problem is most likely in your Java program.
>
> If it doesn't work, you'll need to check your networking configuration or talk to your network administrator for help. Sometimes a firewall installed on your local machine or on your network will prevent you from connecting to the server. If telnet complains that it doesn't know the host name that you're using, most likely your name service (e.g., DNS) isn't properly configured to resolve internet host names. None of these problems are JavaMail or Java problems.
>
> Usually, when you get a low level SocketException when connecting, the problem is due to your networking configuration. Usually it's not a Java problem.
>
> If you've succeeded in connecting with telnet, the next thing to do is to turn on Session debugging and get the protocol trace when JavaMail tries to connect to the remote machine, as described [above](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug). This will often include more detailed error messages from the server that will indicate the real source of the problem.

Comment: yeah, but later found out i had added pin based security verifications so it dint work.. Tried with a different ID and password.